# Как вызвать файл .py передав данные из другого файла .py?

Tags: python

Рассматриваю такой вариант вызова файла pfile.py из другого main.py:

```
from subprocess import call
cmd = 'pfile.py'
call(['python', cmd]
```

вопрос, как передать данные в функцию first() pfile.py файла?

псевдокод:

```
cmd = 'pfile.py first('текст')'
```

Comment: в какую функцию?  если вопрос задан так, как он задан, то - никак.

Comment: Эникейщик, поправил, так получше будет?

Comment: да никакой разницы. У вас проблема XY.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно только в **main.py** импортировать и вызвать функцию `first`

**main.py**

```
import pfile

pfile.first('text')
# Call with: ('text',)
```

**pfile.py**

```
def first(*args):
    print('Call with:', args)
```

---

**Дальше уже идет объяснение и примеры другого пути работы, который я не стал бы рекомендовать**

А то, что у вас это вызов скрипта с указанием аргументов.

Это можно сделать так:

- Обрабатывать значение из `sys.argv`
- Нулевой элемент это текущий путь к файлу, а остальные это аргументы
- Считаем что, 1 элемент это название функции, а остальные параметры это аргументы функции

**pfile.py**

```
import sys


def first(*args):
    print('Call with:', args)


if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    function, *args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(function, args)

    if function == 'first':
        first(*args)
```

Тестирую запуск из консоли:

```
$ python pfile.py first "hello world!" 1 2 3
first ['hello world!', '1', '2', '3']
Call with: ('hello world!', '1', '2', '3')
```

---

Можно и как у вас повторить с кусками кода, тогда нужно работать с `eval`, но потенциально это дыра в безопасности.

```
import sys


def first(*args):
    print('Call with:', args)


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    code = sys.argv[1]
    eval(code)
```

Проверка:

```
python pfile.py first('текст')
Call with: ('текст',)
```

Comment: есть ли замена команде import? Файл mail.py планируется скомпилировать в main.exe. Как реализовать чтобы из exe файла запускались .py?

Comment: @biomotor, отметьте мой ответ, если он ответил на тему в вопросе :) Иначе, желания помогать вам не будет ;) :D

Comment: Держать рядом py файлы или оставить как есть и импортировать, один фиг при генерации в exe импортируемые файлы будут захвачены в exe